# Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin( \frac{x}{n^2}) $ converges pointwise but not uniformly

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ consider the series defined as
$$
S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin( \frac{x}{n^2})
$$
I then have to show that $S$ converges pointwise but not uniformly. I know that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that
$$
|\sin ( \frac{x}{n^2})| \leq \frac{|x|}{n^2}
$$
and I then thought I could use the fact that 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
is a convergent series. Thus Weiterstrass' M-test would say that $S$ converges both uniformly and absolutely but as I have to show that $S$ does not converge uniformly I am little bit lost. How does $x$ change the fact that we cannot use Weiterstrass' M-test in this way? And how do I then show pointwise convergence? Thanks for your help.

Comment: In the Weierstrass $M$-test, the bounds you use for the terms of the series are *not allowed to depend on $x$* (but may depend on $n$). So you can't use $\frac{|x|}{n^2}$ like you did here, since that depends on $x$.

Comment: Thanks. I find it pretty easy to show that a series is uniformly convergent if I am allowed to use Weiterstrass M-test but if I am not I am pretty lost. What can I do here to show pointwise convergence?

Comment: In this question, it is asking you to show that it is *not* uniformly convergent, so Weierstrass $M$-test won't help here (that only lets you show that a series *is* uniformly convergent).

Comment: First of all, try to show pointwise convergence, and to do this, you just need to show that for any fixed $x\in\Bbb{R}$, the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right)$ is a convergent series. Try and think back to your study of series convergence to think about how to show this. (**Hints:** Remember the rules 1) if $\sum |a_n|$ converges, then $\sum a_n$ converges, 2) the Limit Comparison Test, 3) $\lim\limits_{\theta\to0}\frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}=1$.)

Comment: Would it also be possible to assume for a contradiction that $S$ does not converge? This would mean that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$  $\sin(x/n^2)$ does not tend $0$. However, the limit $\sin(x/n^2) \rightarrow 0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$. Thus, a contradiction?

Comment: Well it isn't the case that if a series doesn't converge, then the $n$-th term doesn't tend to $0$. Consider the series $\sum\limits _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ for example (famous Harmonic Series). It doesn't converge, but its terms do go to $0$.

Comment: Ok thanks! I will try to see if I can manage this myself with your hints.

Comment: Your inequality $\left|\sin\left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right)\right|\le\frac{|x|}{n^2}$ establishes pointwise convergence for each $x$.

Comment: How is that @grand_chat?

Comment: By comparison test. You've proved the series $\sum \sin(x/n^2)$ converges absolutely for each $x$

Comment: But does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|x|}{n^2}$ converge for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$? Wouldn't I have to use that to use the comparison test?

Comment: For each $x$ you can pull the constant $x$ out of the summation, and you're left with the convergent series $\sum\frac1{n^2}$.

Comment: But it is not possible to use Weiterstrass M-test in this instance as it may not depend on x?

Comment: If $\sum a_n(x)$ converges uniformly, then $a_n(x)\to 0$ uniformly.  Clearly $\sin(x/n^2)$ fails to converge uniformly to $0$.

Comment: Correct, as mentioned above the M-test requires you to bound your function by something that doesn't depend on $x$. But you don't want to use the M-test anyhow, since you don't have uniform convergence.

Comment: Is the reason that $sin(x/n^2)$ does not tend to $0$ that we can pick $x$ large enough so it does not?

Comment: @mathias $\sin(x/n^2)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.  But the convegence is not uniform on the reals since for, as an example,  $\varepsilon=1/2$ and any $N$ we can find an $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $n>N$ such that $|\sin(x/n^2)|\ge 1/2$.  For example, take $x=\pi n^2/3$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us make things more detailed. Let $S_N$ be the function $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, given by the partial sum
$$
S_N(x) =\sum_{1\le n\le N}\sin\frac x{n^2}\ .
$$
The pointwise convergence, and in the same time the convergence on each compact set $I(K)=[-K, K]$ follows with the argument from the OP. We have on such an interval
w.r.t. the supremum = max norm $\|\cdot\|=\|\cdot\|_\infty$ the estimation
for two indices $M,N$ with $M>N$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|S_M-S_N\|
&=\max_{-K\le x\le K}\left|\sum_{N<n\le M}\sin\frac x{n^2}\right|
\\
&\le \max_{-K\le x\le K}\sum_{N<n\le M}\left|\sin\frac x{n^2}\right|
\\
&\le \max_{-K\le x\le K}\sum_{N<n\le M}\left|\frac x{n^2}\right|
\\
&\le K\sum_{N<n\le M}\frac 1{n^2}
\\
&\le K\sum_{N<n\le M}\frac 1{n(n-1)}
\\
&\le \frac KN\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So given an $\epsilon>0$ we make the choice of $N(\epsilon):=\frac K\epsilon$, for for all $M,N$ with $M>N>N(\epsilon)$ we have $\|S_M-S_N\|<\epsilon$. The space of continuous functions on the compact interval $I(K)=[-K,K]$ is a Banach space with the supremum norm, so there is a limit.

---

Let us show that there is no uniform convergence on $\Bbb R$. Assume the contrary. 
Then there exists a limit $S$, a continuous function. (Because it is continuous on each interval $[-K,K]$.)
For $\epsilon:=1/3$ there exists an $N(1/3)$ so that for all $N\ge N(1/3)$ we have $\|S-S_N\|\le 1/3$. In particular, $1=\|S_{N+1}-S_N\|\le 2/3$. Contradiction.