# Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin \left( \frac{x}{n^2} \right)$ does not converge uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I asked this question about a week ago but I am little bit unsure about the way to solve it so I hope it is ok if I ask again about some things I do not fully understand.

I have to show that the series
$$
S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin \left( \frac{x}{n^2} \right)
$$
does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ which can be shown by showing that 
$
\sin \left( \frac{x}{n^2} \right)
$ fails to uniformly converge towards $0$ when $n$ tends to $\infty$. Is this because of contraposition? I know that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges unifomrly then $a_n$ converges uniformly towards $0$.

Futhermore, by negation we have that $\sin \left( \frac{x}{n^2} \right)$ does not converge uniformly towards $0$ when $n$ tends to $\infty$ if 
$$
\exists \epsilon > 0 \ \forall N \in \mathbb{N} \ \exists x \in \mathbb{R} \ \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \ : n \geq N \ \text{and} \left|\sin \left( \frac{x}{n^2} \right)\right| \geq \epsilon
$$
If I then pick $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ and $x = \frac{\pi n^2}{3}$ I get the desired result but don't I also have to pick a specific $n \in \mathbb{N}$ so that this only works when $n \geq N$? Or is it simply enough to pick $\epsilon$ and $x$?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The series of functions is Uniformly convergent at any $[a,b]$.

Comment: I assume [this was your earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3687337/show-that-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-sin-fracxn2-converges-pointwi)

Comment: As stated, the question makes no sense. It doesn't converge uniformly *where*?

Comment: I am sorry. I have edited now. I have to show it does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I would expect you to pick $x$ and $n$ as functions of $\epsilon$ and $N$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning your first question: yes, it is by contraposition.

The proof that your sequence does not converge uniformly to $0$ is almost correct. Simply take $x=\dfrac{\pi N^2}3$ (instead of $x=\dfrac{\pi n^2}3$). Then, there is a $\varepsilon>0$ (namely, $\dfrac12$) such that, for every $N\in\Bbb N$, there is some natural $n\geqslant N$ (namely, $N$ itself) and some number $x$ such that $\left|\sin\left(\dfrac x{n^2}\right)\right|\geqslant\dfrac12$.

Comment: Ok I think I understand now. Thanks for your time once again, Jose.

Comment: Are you always able to pick the natural number $n$ to be $N$? such that $n \geq N$ or does it only work in some scenarios?

Comment: @Mathias Why? If $x=\frac{\pi N^2}3$, then $\left|\sin\left(\frac x{N^2}\right)\right|=\frac12$.

Comment: Now I think I got confused again. I thought if we picked $\frac{\pi n^2}{3}$ (which was not correct I know) one would have that $\left|\sin( \frac{\pi n^2}{3n^2})\right| = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \geq \frac{1}{2}$ but I don't see how this is the same as what you just wrote?

Comment: My mistake. I meant $\frac{\sqrt3}2$.

Comment: Ok thanks. But the reason that we pick $n$ to be $N$ in this case is so that when $n \geq N$ we have that $\left|\sin( \frac{\pi N^2}{3N^2})\right| = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \geq \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: No! All we want is that *there is some* $n\geqslant N$ such that $\left|\sin\left(\frac x{n^2}\right)\right|\geqslant\frac12$. And, with my choice of $x$, taking $n=N$ will do.

Comment: Ok but $\left|\sin( \frac{\pi N^2}{3N^2})\right| = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \geq \frac{1}{2}$ is still correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.